# Is "Law of Leaky Abstractions" a proper noun?

Tags: writing, capitalization

From [Leaky abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction) (Wikipedia),

> As coined by Spolsky, the Law of Leaky Abstractions states "All non-trivial abstractions, to some degree, are leaky."

I am not sure if *Law of Leaky Abstractions* is correct. Which of the following statements are correct (if any)?

1. *Law of Leaky Abstractions* is a proper noun. It is correct as is.
2. *Leaky Abstractions* is a proper noun, and it should be *law of Leaky Abstractions*
3. It should be *law of leaky abstractions* (as in several places in [the original source](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html)). No proper nouns or capitalisation. *Law of Leaky Abstractions* is an example of [willy-nilly capitalisation of words](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/how-to-write-a-better-resume.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

*The Law of Leaky Abstractions* is a *title*, not a noun. There are no nouns in that title that are proper nouns. They are all common nouns, but they are capitalized because they are in a title.

Comment: The quote in the question is not a title. The sentence is in the body text of the Wikipedia article: "As coined by Spolsky, the Law of Leaky Abstractions states "All non-trivial abstractions, to some degree, are leaky."". Do you mean the capitalisation from the title has leaked into the body text and statement 3 is correct?

Comment: @Peter Mortensen, it's not a title in the sense that you assume, ie. on the wikipedia page. It's a title of a concept / axiom, in the same way that "Murphy's Law" is. So it's proper usage is to be capitalized.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: Yes, *Law of Leaky Abstractions* is a proper noun.  This "law" is a singular, named entity and it is appropriate to treat its name in the fashion of any other proper noun.